# Possible way to rearrange form to use two row instead of one

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form, but so far it's one row and it's not to much user-friendly, also, I tried to resize the height of the form but it's also bad because the form is too long then.

You can see I have fields as: `amount`, `note`, `date` and at the end option list.

I want to have `amount` and `note` in one row and below them `date` and `optionList`

So it look like this:

`amount note`

`date optionList`

`create cancel`

So far I tried to use `display: grid` but nothing is changed

Here is the code:

```css
.transaction-group{
 position:relative;
 top:50px;
 text-align:left;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.date-balance {
  background-color:
    #e0ddcf;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    0 4px 6px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;

}

#left {
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="transaction-group" th:each="singleGroup  : ${transactionGroup}">
  <div class="date-balance">
    <h1 id="left">123</h1>
    <h2 id="right">Balance <span>32.0</span></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself.

Comment: Expanding on DD's comment, adding a link to a live example *in addition* to having code in the question is welcomed, but all relevant [code](//help/mcve) should at least be posted in the question itself. For HTML, CSS an JS, the [Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/90527) feature allows you to create a [live example](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/90527) on SO itself.

Comment: The code you have posted appears to be unrelated to your question/problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Flexbox. Set up rows and cols on your HTML. Add class to "transaction-group" and make the display to flex and the flex-direction to column so that rows will stack. Look at the code below. I just added some extra styling to make it more appealling but this basically does the

Amount Note
Date optionList
create Cancel

format.

```css
.transaction-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.col {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="transaction-group" th:each="singleGroup  : ${transactionGroup}">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label for="amount">AMOUNT:</label>
      <input type="text" id="amount">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label for="note">NOTE:</label>
      <input type="text" id="note">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label for="date">DATE:</label>
      <input type="text" id="date">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label for="optionList">OPTION LIST:</label>
      <select id="optionList">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with flexbox for this is that the columns in the various rows won't necessarily be aligned. If you were to reverse the columns in the second row, for example, the layout is less appealing. CSS grid would be better. Flexbox is one-dimensional, whereas grid is two-dimensional.